# "Integrate with Google" button URL returns 404

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

We have GoogleApps Marketplace app where we're using "Integrate with Google" button to start the google OAuth2 process. The button disappeared two - three days ago. We're receiving the error 404 on the button URL.
This was working for years (expect same issue in 2018).

Is this something made by Google? As we didn't change anything in the app.

Thanks

Comment: Can you point us to any reference about the "integrate with Google" button you are referring to?

Comment: Sure : There was a link that now is also 404 : https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button  . Those are previous issues in the tacker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160044707 , https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148242341, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110862188 And seems that google confirmed that issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169585808  : "The issue has been identified and we are working on a fix, thanks for the reports.". And even more, right after this confirmation, google fixed the issue.

Comment: After 10 days the issue is back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As updated in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169585808, we have fixed this issue already. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Well, the issue is back again, just aster 10 days , common google, you can do better.