# “Integrate with Google” button URL returns 404

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

Well, I've asked this question 2 weeks ago (["Integrate with Google" button URL returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127011/integrate-with-google-button-url-returns-404)):

> We have GoogleApps Marketplace app where we're using "Integrate with Google" button to start the google OAuth2 process. The button disappeared two - three days ago. We're receiving the error 404 on the button URL. This was working for years (expect same issue in 2018).
> Is this something made by Google? As we didn't change anything in the app.

Than after 3 days google fixed the issue, and 2 weeks after same issue is back.

Comment: This is stackoverflow, not google support.

Comment: I can see from the post you linked that you already commented on Google Issue Tracker that the issue still persists - so I assume that Google will take care of it. On stackoverflow people cannot help you if the bug is from Google's side.

Comment: Yes, I opened, but google advise if need support to ask here as well.Thanks